# Hangout Developer Sandbox Won't Load App

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Sometime on Friday Feb 8th, I noticed none of my hangout apps would load in the developer sandbox.

I am getting a javascript error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when hangouts tries to load https://login.corp.google.com/request?s=oz-autopush-full.plus.corp.google.com:443/uberproxy/OaxXYqZ2rrY/&d=https://oz-autopush-full.plus.corp.google.com/js/api.js&maxAge=1200&authLevel=2000000&rpMode=v2&keyIds=Do0.

My apps were working before this, now they get stuck at the loading screen: [hangout app stuck at the loading screen http://skitch.ubermajestix.com/Google%2B_Hangouts-20130211-085412.jpg](http://skitch.ubermajestix.com/Google%2B_Hangouts-20130211-085412.jpg).

This happens even with the SimpleHangoutApp (https://plushangoutstarter.appspot.com/static/simpleHangoutApp.xml). Am I missing something here or is the url above trying to pull in api.js not working?

Comment: Thanks @prisoner, the apps seem to be loading again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with the sandbox over the weekend, and it should now be fixed. Please try again and confirm.